# HtmlUnit WebDriver and clicking on image input types but Page not reloading as expected

Tags: javascript, image, selenium, htmlunit

I apologize if this question has been asked before but I did not find anything.

I have a web page with a sorting icon that is of input type "image". Now if I find this image by name via ChromeDriver and click, when I get the page source I can see that changes have been made to this page. However with HtmlUnit it does not seem to work. I'm wondering if anyone else has had this issue before, and rather they narrowed it down to HtmlUnit and the clicking of images or was it a problem with javascript.

I have tried enabling JS with HtmlUnit, and simulating Chrome with HtmlUnit Driver. Given limitations I can not use Chromedriver over HtmlUnit. Thanks.

I can only given a sample of the html tag that contains the input tag:

input type="image" name="sortNameUp" border="0" src="/images/move_down.gif"/

Comment: Please post your complete case, so others can reproduce the issue

Comment: It is not a public website unfortunately....

Comment: Please read http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/submittingJSBugs.html